# asp.net mvc inputs extremely slow on ipad

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a huuge problem. I developed an application in ASP.NET MVC 4, all works well except on Ipad (Ipad R2 IOS9.2 - but happened to others also) / tested with Safari and Chrome.

It seems that in every input it takes very long to type each character. 
The inputs are done in the standard mvc way:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Name" } })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

However when I used a text area field, it worked OK.

When I replaced with a simple html `<input>` it worked OK with safari, chrome was still being slow.

I disabled client side validation and still no change.

I do no want to replace all my mvc code with basic HTML
Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Have you tried replacing Html.EditorFor with Html.TextBoxFor to see if the performance improves? There seems to be an occasional performance issue with EditorFor (http://forums.asp.net/t/1676500.aspx?Performance+issue+with+EditorFor+and+page+with+a+large+number+of+inputs)

Comment: Slow performance usually means something is up with the JavaScript, especially on mobile devices. I don't imagine a small difference in HTML is causing massive issues performance.

Comment: I made the replacement with Html.TextBoxFor, but got the same behavior :(    Apparently Chrome and Safari have the problem on Ipad, but not Firefox.. very very strange..

Answer (score 1):

I've got an update - which kinda solves the symptom but not the disease.

Apparently the issue was caused by a large html select with a lot of options in the same form. Outside of the form in the **same page** inputs would behave properly, but inside that form (even a basic html input) would be "slowed" down.

Firefox was the only one that played nice to it.  The input was populated through ajax but I would say straight forward ajax, nothing fancy that would have caused a problem..